# How link data - delimiter

Tags: sql-server, pivot

How can I make script take mydata from mytable instead of providing values like in an example below?
SO instead of set values to Code and Location link these to mycolumns in mytables?

```
with data as (
    select Code,Location from ( values
        ('L698-W-EA',          NULL)
       ,('L82009-EA',          '1/22/333/4444/55555')
       ,('L80401-A-EA',        '7/88/999/10-10/12')
       ,('CWD2132W-BOX-25PK',  'A-AISLE')
       ,('GM22660003-EA',      'B1K2')
    )
    data(Code,Location)
)
,shredded as
(
    select Code,Location,t.*
    from data
    cross apply [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](data.Location,'/') as t
)
select 
    pvt.Code
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[1],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc1
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[2],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc2
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[3],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc3
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[4],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc4
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[5],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc5 
from shredded
pivot (max(Item) for ItemNumber in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) pvt;
;
go
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is using a "Common Table Expressions" or "CTE". You can use temporary tables instead:

```
select Code,Location 
INTO #data
from ( values
        ('L698-W-EA',          NULL)
       ,('L82009-EA',          '1/22/333/4444/55555')
       ,('L80401-A-EA',        '7/88/999/10-10/12')
       ,('CWD2132W-BOX-25PK',  'A-AISLE')
       ,('GM22660003-EA',      'B1K2')
    ) x


select Code,Location,t.*
INTO #shredded
from #data
cross apply [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](#data.Location,'/') as t


select 
    pvt.Code
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[1],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc1
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[2],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc2
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[3],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc3
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[4],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc4
   ,cast(isnull(pvt.[5],' ') as varchar(8)) as Loc5 
from #shredded
pivot (max(Item) for ItemNumber in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) pvt
```